# How to make a python script run 15 minutes after system startup?

Tags: python, linux

I wrote a script a python which reminds me to open WhatsApp Web whenever chrome browser is opened. To run this script each time, I have to use the terminal to make the python script run. I want to make the script run automatically 15-20 minutes after the system starts.

Here's my code:

```
import webbrowser
import os
import signal
import tkMessageBox
from subprocess import check_output
from crontab import CronTab


def get_pid(name):
    return int(check_output(["pidof","-s",name]))
'''Script to open whatsapp web whenever chrome is opened'''

cron=CronTab()
job=cron.new(command='/usr/bin/echo')
job.minute.during(1,50).every(1)
name="chrome"
if (get_pid(name)):
    webbrowser.open('http://web.whatsapp.com')
    tkMessageBox.showinfo(title="Greetings", message="Connect your         phone to chrome to open whatsapp!")
```

I tried editing the crontab, but that did not prove very helpful. Is there any way to do so?

Edit-1 
Here's my updated code, and it still doesn't seem to work. When I manually run the script, it works, but otherwise not(on reboot).

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python
    import webbrowser
import os
import signal
import tkMessageBox
from subprocess import check_output
import time

def get_pid(name):
    return int(check_output(["pidof","-s",name]))


'''Script to open whatsapp web whenever chrome is opened'''

name="chrome"
while(1):
    time.sleep(600)
    while(get_pid(name)):
        webbrowser.open('http://web.whatsapp.com')
        tkMessageBox.showinfo(title="Greetings", message="Connect your phone to chrome to open whatsapp!")
        print "Hey"
```

Apart from this, I added the following lines in crontab:

```
@reboot /usr/bin/python /path/to/whatsapp.py &
```

Further, I made a .conf file which looks like this :

```
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

exec /path/to/whatsapp.py
```

And the most recent log file for this looks like this:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/whatsapp.py", line 17, in <module>
    while(get_pid(name)):
  File "/path/to/whatsapp.py", line 10, in get_pid
    return int(check_output(["pidof","-s",name]))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 573, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['pidof', '-s', 'chrome']' returned non-zero exit status 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/whatsapp.py", line 20, in <module>
    tkMessageBox.showinfo(title="Greetings", message="Connect your phone to chrome to open whatsapp!")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/tkMessageBox.py", line 83, in showinfo
    return _show(title, message, INFO, OK, **options)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/tkMessageBox.py", line 72, in _show
    res = Message(**options).show()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/tkCommonDialog.py", line 44, in show
    w = Frame(self.master)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 2537, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'frame', cnf, {}, extra)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 2049, in __init__
    BaseWidget._setup(self, master, cnf)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 2024, in _setup
    _default_root = Tk()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1767, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

where path/to is obviously the path to the script.

Comment: Check out the anachronistic time daemon `atd`. Trigger the execution on boot with 15 minutes delay.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solutions are often the best: Make the script run on boot, and then sleep for 15 min.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure doing cron-related tasks via python will help you solve your issue. Crontab takes a special syntax for scheduling a command after a reboot, so you would likely do a

```
@reboot python /my/python/path/message.py
```

If you want the bulk of this code to run 15 minutes after reboot, probably tell the python script itself to sleep for the fifteen minutes:

```
import time
time.sleep(900) # 900 = 60 * 15
```

Comment: Where shall i add the ' @reboot ... ' statement ? And does this mean that I do not have to type './message.py' everytime I want to run this script ?

Comment: Open the crontab with `crontab -e` and add the @reboot line. Add the python to the top of your python script (or inside your`if  __name__ == '__main__'` block)

Comment: This will cause the script to run 15 minutes after reboot. Opening your crontab can be confusing because I'm pretty sure the default editor is VIM, which you may not be familiar with. Press 'i', type in the command listed above, press 'Esc' and then close the editor by typing ':q' and pressing enter.

Comment: The editor which opened was nano. I am familiar with it. But when I made the mentioned changes and rebooted my system, nothing happened. The path in the @reboot line is the place where my file is located. Could you help where I might be going wrong?

Comment: With the python update, you shouldn't see anything happen for ~15 minutes -- when the popup should finally appear. Try running it without the sleep statement and it should pop up within a minute or so. Maybe try creating a file in your python script so you can check if the issue is that the script isn't running or if actually your popup isn't displaying for some reason. You can probably remove all the "cron" lines from your code as well. & It looks like the popup will only show if chrome is open, maybe you want to remove the `if get_pid(name)):` line so it always runs?

Comment: Posted an updated code, as well as whatever I have tried up till now. Sadly, nothing seems to work for me.